# Passing variable to a class in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
arr = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10, 0)}
```

How would i access the array in a different class file to read and write it.

I've looked at a lot of places but they don't seem to explain it very clearly.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your question is rather vague. Can you give a more complete example? For example, can you provide the code of the class where you would need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the usage below

```
class ArrayHolder
  #Define a array as a class variable
  @@myArray = Array.new()

  #define accessor methods
  def self.MyArray
    @@myArray
  end
  def self.MyArray=(val)
    @@myArray = val
  end
end

#Calling the array holder in another class
ArrayHolder.MyArray << 3
puts ArrayHolder.MyArray

newArr = Array.new
newArr <<1
newArr <<2


ArrayHolder.MyArray =newArr

puts ArrayHolder.MyArray
```

Hope this help